# Switching tabs made using CSS inside click event

Tags: css, redirect, radio-button

I have implemented tabbed browsing using this http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/ 
I have a click event inside one of my tabs(say tab1). Is there some way I can redirect from tab1 to tab3 inside this click event??Since, the link says 'no javascript', I am skeptical whether this can be done or not

Comment: This technique simply uses hidden radio buttons to trigger which tab gets displayed – so it should be as simple a checking a different radio button via JS.

Comment: @nisha, there is no way of redirecting from tab1 to tab3 this using only css, you have to use jquery for this, also the existing code will not work below IE9 browsers as well as in mobile

Answer (score 0):

Adding this inside the eventlistener code works:

```
 document.getElementById("tab-3").checked = true;
```